# Remove items (superstrings) from array where a substring exists as another item

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to filter an array where I want to exclude anything that has a 'substring' in the array.
This is to create an array of search terms but limit the number of duplicate searches.

i.e.

```
[ "Rough Collie", "Alsatian", "Standard Poodle", "Poodle", "Collie", "Schnauser", "Border Collie", "Chihuahua" ]
=>
[ "Alsatian", "Poodle", "Collie", "Schnauser", "Chihuahua" ]
```

Where we've removed Standard Poodle, because Poodle is a match and Rough Collie and Border Collie because Collie is a match. 
i.e. if a word exists but also exists as a substring in another term, remove the longer term.

```
arr - arr.map { |a| arr.select { |s| s.include?(a) && s != a}}.flatten
```

this basically works but looks a bit ugly. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id suggest:

```
arr.delete_if{|c|
  arr.any? { |s| c != s && c.include?(s) }
}
```

`arr` will be modified inplace, so saving memory allocations

Comment: That's what I was after. Might be worthwhile adding a uniq! clause in there as suggested below. i'll make the edit.

Comment: If `arr = ["a", "cat"]` your method returns `["a"]`. You can fix that by changing the inner block to `{ |s| c!=s && c =~ /\b#{s}\b/ }` (`\b` being a word break). Notice that permits `arr = ["b c", "a b c"]` to return `["b c"]`, as I expect it should.  Also, `delete_if` (aka `reject!`) mutates `arr`, unlike the OP's code. You can avoid that by using `reject` rather than `delete_if`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be as follows:

```
arr.uniq!
arr.reject { |ar| arr.select { |another| ar.include? another }.count >= 2 }
```